# entryfile not found in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose project made up of five docker containers, three of which use an entrypoint.sh file. None of these three can find the entrypoint.sh file after building.

Ive tried several variations on the syntax but I am very new to docker and wouldnt know a syntax error if I was staring right at it. The build process for each completes without errors, but when I try to bring them online they cannot find the entrypoint file and continually restart in a loop.

The Dockerfile for one such

```
(a bunch of confidential stuff I cant post here)
# Enable apache modules
RUN sudo a2enmod actions headers  alias deflate mime expires filter setenvif include rewrite
# Create a log file
RUN mkdir /var/www/logs
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/logs
#Open up needed ports
EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 80
ADD entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh
```

aaand the error

```
ss-fe-webserver | /bin/sh: 1: ./entrypoint.sh: not found
```

Its worth noting that I am running Docker for Windows, and these Dockerfiles were written by a Mac user. As long as this error persists, the servers continually restart and do not stay online.

Comment: simply add `RUN ls` after `ADD entrypoint.sh /` to check path of `./entrypoint.sh` inside container

Comment: what is your `WORKDIR`? or paste your entire `DOCKERFILE`

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your entrypoint at `/` path. It seems like you are using `WORKDIR` somewhere which is causing this conflict.
2. Prefer using `COPY` instead of `ADD` in this case.
3. Provide executable permissions to your entrypoint script.

Here is how it may look like at the end -

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Rebuilt entire project with this code added, error changed to :
ss-fe-webserver | standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

You add the entrypoint.sh on root folder as "/".

`ADD entrypoint.sh /`

But you still call the entrypoint.sh on ./ as workdir folder.

`ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh`

You try:

`ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh`

or:

`ADD entrypoint.sh ./`

Comment: Tried this code change, rebuilt and got the same error.